# Взять только первое вхождение строки присоединяемой таблицы в SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть две таблицы.

Такая TABLE_1:

```
A_ID     B
=============
  1      2
  2      64
  3      87
```

И такая TABLE_2:

```
B_ID     A_A_ID     C
========================
  1        1        'HELLO, '
  2        1        'CRUEL '
  3        2        'WORLD'
  4        3        '!'
```

Нужно так соединить TABLE_1 и TABLE_2, чтобы при внешнего ключа A_A_ID => A_ID к таблице TABLE_1 из таблицы TABLE_2 выбиралась только одна строка (с меньшим B_ID). То есть должны получить:

```
A_ID     B      B_ID     A_A_ID      C
============================================
  1      2       1         1       'HELLO, '
  2      64      3         2       'WORLD'
  3      87      4         3       '!'
```

Comment: соединяете как есть, а данные первой строки получаете с помощью `keep (dense_rank first)` http://www.sql.ru/blogs/oracleandsql/2145

Comment: @Mike что-то я не вполне понимаю. По вашей ссылке речь всегда об агрегатных функциях (MAX, COUNT и т.д.). Можете привести пример с этими двумя таблицами?

Comment: О, это особенность синтаксиса Oracle. Сам не понимаю зачем они так придумали. Всех сбивает с толку. Ни каких агрегатных функций на самом деле нет. Это только кажется, что там min. Никакой разницы от того какая функция используется вообще нет. min/max/avg совместно с keep даст один и тот же результат, а именно - информацию из первой строки в выбранном порядке сортировки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сейчас обходное решение запилил, т.к. демо-данных мало, но лишний запрос - не огонь, не думаю, что подойдет:

```
SELECT A_ID, B, B_ID, A_A_ID, C 
  FROM TABLE_1 T1, TABLE_21 T2 
  WHERE T1.A_ID = T21.A_A_ID 
    AND TABLE_2.B_ID = (SELECT MIN(T22.B_ID) 
                          FROM TABLE_2 T22 
                          WHERE T1.A_ID = T22.A_A_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно через оконные функции, но они медленнее.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
  FROM table_1 t1
       LEFT JOIN ( 
                    SELECT MIN(t.b_id) b_id, t.a_a_id 
                    FROM table_2 t
                    GROUP BY t.a_a_id
                  ) tr 
             ON tr.a_a_id = t1.a_id
       LEFT JOIN table_2 t2
             ON t2.b_id = tr.b_id
```